# Some part of my Django form should change based on TypedChoiceField list selection

Tags: html, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-views

I am new to Django. I have a requirement where in based on the TypedChoiceField list selection some part of the form should be changed. Meaning for a particular selection I need some fields to be displayed on the webpage and for other selection I need some other fields to be displayed on the webpage.

If there is already a similar page existing, please point me to that page, it will help me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I would do is set up a javascript static file (here's a [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial06/)) that hides and shows elements using the `select` method.

For example, if you had categories that each needed a different set of fields, you could put all your categories into a `<select>` element and then using some simple JS, display the desired fields:

```
$("#select_object").change(function () {
    toggleFields();
});
```

In that case, `#select_object` would be that `<select>` element. Whenever it changes (the user selects something) it shows the fields you want.